# Normalizing using inital feature name adds second feature with same name

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am using `ml.net` for a small project and playing around with normalization. I can do normalization in two ways, keeping the original feature column name or defining a new column (second line of code).

```
dataProcessPipelineTransformations = dataProcessPipelineTransformations.Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(featureSet.FeatureName, fixZero: false));
dataProcessPipelineTransformations = dataProcessPipelineTransformations.Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("normalizedFeature", featureSet.FeatureName, fixZero: false));
```

If I go with the initial feature name, I found out, that `ml.net` adds a second column with the same name.

[image: Two features with same name "Open"]

I am asking myself, why does the framework know, which of the two columns should be used for training? Does it always go with the normalized data (IsNormalized)?

Thx for clearing up this thing, I did not find any documentation for this behavior.

Best regards
flotschi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to inspect the [DataViewSchema.Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.dataviewschema.column?view=ml-dotnet), you'll notice that there's a boolean flag `IsHidden`. When you output the results of a transform to a column with the same name, the type and values of the new column are the ones that are used for downstream operations. The old column is hidden and therefore no longer accessible by name. Therefore, if you need access to the data before normalization, it's recommended to output to a column with a different name.